# Unnecessary permission is found in app content on play store

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions

I have updated my application and removed below permission from my update bundle but still it is showing on play store console in app content  sensitive permission.

```
4 previously declared permissions
android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG
android.permission.SEND_SMS
android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

[image]

Comment: You are probably getting those from some library. Check the "Merged Manifest" sub-tab of the `AndroidManifest.xml` editor to try to see where they are coming from.

Comment: I have added these permissions in previous updated bundle which is rejected. so I have removed these permission from manifest and update new bundle but permission didn't remove from app content sensitive permission. I have checked in lib also and these permission is not available.